# Is it possible using a vscode extension to get info on or even interact with other instances?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to find a way to get the open projects in all open vscode instances using a custom extension. I have done some research but I'm not finding any information on this is the API docs. I am guessing this isn't something built into vscode's API.

I think I can fix it by using 1 file to write some JSON to when an editor opens, but I would like to know if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode indeed starts a separate extension host process for each instance, so it's almost completely isolated. The only workaround within the API I can think of is using the global / workspace state API, see here for more information:

[How to persist information for a vscode extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821924/how-to-persist-information-for-a-vscode-extension/51822055#51822055)

Data persisted to a memento should be available to all instances. The tricky part would be figuring out when a particular memento value has changed, I don't think there's any event for this, so you might have to resort to polling.

Other than that, persisting something to the file system or perhaps using sockets might be an option. Note that the `ExtensionContext` exposes a [`storagePath`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext.storagePath) that might be helpful for the former.

Comment: Allright thanks. So I'm guessing since everything is isolated, it's also not possible to "remotely" close other instances?

Comment: Not with the API at least, as far as I know. I guess nothing stops you from just killing a particular process via Node API though. Or setting some flag in the global storage that is polled and calls the "close window" command for a specific workspace URI.