# VSCode Extension - Updating Value of Extension Configuration

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Working on a VS Code extension, I am trying to add functionality inside of an async function that will update a value of the configuration from the extension.

Relevant part of the package.json:

```
    "contributes": {
        "configuration": {
            "title": "Extension Features",
            "properties": {
                "myextension.currentOrg": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "orgId": "",
                    "orgUsername": "",
                    "orgSecret": "",
                    "orgLoginUrl": "",
                    "description": "myextension.currentOrg description",
                    "default": {
                        "orgId": "",
                        "orgUsername": "",
                        "orgSecret": "",
                        "orgLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com"
                    } 
                },
                "myextension.saveOrgData": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": true,
                    "description": "myextension.saveOrgData description"
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

In my async function, I am trying to do the equivalent of this:

```
let currentSecret = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("myextension.currentOrg").get("orgSecret");

if(currentSecret == "") {
  vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("myextension.currentOrg").update("orgSecret", "1234");
}
```

Since `.update()` return a `Thenable`, can someone help explain how to wrap this correctly in a promise?

If I even try running the `.update()` command above from the REPL in debug mode, the configuration does not change, and I'm not clear as to why.

Here's a sample of my function

```
  public async run(): Promise<any> {

    let clientSecret: string;
    const currentDoc = this.getCurrentDocument();
    const currentWorkspace = this.getWorkspaceRoot();
    const orgData = customUtils.getConnectedOrgSync();

    let clientIdPreSplit = orgData.split("\n")[7].split(' ');
    let clientId = clientIdPreSplit[clientIdPreSplit.length - 1];
    // check the extension config

    // extension's default value for myextension.currentOrg.orgSecret is set to ""
    let currentSecret = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("wfdx.currentOrg").get("orgSecret");

if(currentSecret == "") {
  vscode.window.showInformationMessage("updating config...");

  // this does not appear to update the extension's config in the 'contributes' section of package.json
  await vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("myextension.currentOrg").update("orgSecret", "1234");
} else {
    clientSecret = await showInputBox();
}

    const jsonProjectInfo = fs.readFileSync(`${currentWorkspace}`+'/sfdx-project.json', "utf-8");
    let projectAsJSON = JSON.parse(jsonProjectInfo);
    let loginURL = projectAsJSON["sfdcLoginUrl"];

    const jsf = new jsforce.Connection({
      loginUrl: loginURL,
      clientId: clientId,
      clientSecret: clientSecret
    });
...
// more file manipulation logic
return jsf;
}
```

Any and all help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a complete code example of something that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @Gama11 I just added in an example of the async function that isn't working as expected

Comment: You might have some misconception about what `update()` does? From the code comment, it sounds like you expect it to modify your extension's `package.json` file. It modifies `settings.json`.

Comment: Cheers @Gama11, certainly a misconception on my part. Was hoping that would be a quick fix. I went through some GitHub issues around this, doesn't seem to be a method to change the config values that way. Will have to see what else exists. I guess I could just target the extension's package.json with `fs`

Comment: You're not really meant to modify the `package.json`, not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Maybe storing something in `globalState` would make more sense? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821924/how-to-persist-information-for-a-vscode-extension/51822055

Comment: @Gama11 I'll have to look at `globalState`. What I'm trying to do is just establish a connection to Salesforce through JSForce. The goal is ultimately to make a file deploy to SF when a save event happens, and the JSForce connection requires a password, so I'm just trying to devise a way to get it from the user if there's nothing in the config via InputBox, otherwise pull it from a file so the user doesn't have to enter it each time

Comment: Sounds like persisting it to `globalState` would solve your issue, though I'm not sure that's necessarily the best / safest way to store passwords.. Looks like it was once consisdered to provide something for that out of the box in the VSCode API, but then decided against: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15414

Comment: @Gama11 that's more what I was afraid of. It looks like Salesforce's DX CLI (what I'm building on top of) stores json files on Windows in %USERPROFILE%\.sfdx. It stores the Id, loginUrl, and clientId that I'm after, along with an access and refresh token, but still would have to get the password and store somewhere to avoid a bad user experience