# Show message when VSCode Extension is updated

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I developing a VSCode extension called [Ifc-Syntax](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alanrynne.ifc-syntax) and I'm having trouble finding how to do a somewhat simple thing:

Every time I publish a new update to my extension, any user that has this extension installed will get the update automatically. Some extensions notify the user with a message and a link to the Changelog, which I find extremely useful, specially when the extension has new capabilities.

I'm assuming there is some method in the VSCode Extensions API to notify of an extension update, but I have not found it.
Another option would be to implement a 'first load' procedure, but that would mean I'd have to cache a boolean value `isFirstLoad` or `hasLoadedBefore` somewhere, which I have no idea how to do to be honest. :(

Hopefully a more enlightened person will be able to point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Comment: I think extensions usually just store something in the `globalState` for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821924/how-to-persist-information-for-a-vscode-extension/51822055#51822055

Comment: And there it was! I guess it was staring at me the whole time... thanks! If you put this as an answer I will accept it as valid ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I feel like I'd just be duplicating my other answer I linked. :)

Comment: True to that.... XD Quarantine is making me an idiot... haha I flagged it as a duplicate